# Insert large binary file or array (over 64MB) into Cassandra using datastax c++ driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I'm looking for a way to Insert large binary file or array (over 64MB) into Cassandra using datastax c++ driver.

I know Cassandra has a 64MB limit for blobs, but as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713038/nosql-mongodb-vs-cassandra) implies

Datastax have a solution for that, but I can't find any examples in their API which prove that ability.

I'm also aware of the astyanax project by netflix, but it's written in java.

I'm talking about really large files, around 10GB each.
I've succeeded in doing that using mongodb+gridfs, but wondered if Cassandra would perform better in terms of write performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is not built for large object storage.

You can either chunk the file into small blobs, perhaps 128k each, or try using CFS.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-file-system-design

Comment: The CFS is not mentioned in the cpp driver API, could you please refer me to a code example?, or is CFS a java only library?

Comment: Wow, that's good to know.  I was thinking of archive files in Cassandra as blobs.  Is there another NoSQL database that would be good for "large object storage"?

Comment: Sounds like you need a file system